# How do I group/summarize this data in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say I have this data in a spreadsheet

```
+-------+---------+--------+
| Name  | Letters | Number |
+-------+---------+--------+
| Bob   | a,b,c   | 1,2,3  |
+-------+---------+--------+
| Bob   | d       | 4      |
+-------+---------+--------+
| Bob   | b,c     | 3,5    |
+-------+---------+--------+
| Alice | e       | 5      |
+-------+---------+--------+
```

How do I write a formula that displays this data like this?

```
+-------+---------+-----------+
| Name  | Letters | Number    |
+-------+---------+-----------+
| Bob   | a,b,c,d | 1,2,3,4,5 |
+-------+---------+-----------+
| Alice | e       | 5         |
+-------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Please include a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested by [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Without a script easier (or perhaps only fesible?) with two formulae and the manula addition of `Letters` and `Number`. Assuming `Name` is in A1, in say D1:

```
=unique(A:A)
```

Then in E2 copied across to F2 and the pair down to suit:

```
=join(",",unique(sort(transpose(split(join(",",filter(B2:B,$A2:$A=$D2)),",")),1,1)))
```

For syntax [see](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?visit_id=1-636418245013322991-3941894431&hl=en-GB&rd=2).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the aggregate by column function on this:
https://tools.guanxi.ai/#/aggregate-by-column

1. Master column: Name
2. Aggregate: Letters, Numbers
3. Columns to Deduplicate: Name 
   // So you're left with only 2 rows not four
4. Deduplicate within Aggregated cell: Yes
   // This is to prevent having 'b' twice in the final version